# How to I configure a relative path to use when generating build outputs in Vite?

Tags: javascript, html, vite

In my app, when I do npm run dev I can test fine on `http://localhost:3000`. But for the output build, where I run it, is part of another application sub folder. For example, the links ends up being like `http://myapp.com/docs/reconstatus` as I dump the dist output from the vite app into the reconstatus folder and to view the app I just go to `http://myapp.com/docs/reconstatus/index.html`. I noticed a problem where the generated code links to the `js/css/etc...` set by vite start with a slash, so relative to the root, but this results in 404 can't find files, since now the files are in `/docs/reconstatus`. Is there a way to tell vite, for build outputs, set the links to use a certain path like `/docs/reconstatus`?

Comment: https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-base  maybe?

Answer (score 5):

I assume you want to configure your public base path for your vite build. Tell me if i am wrong and i will edit the answer.

To configure the public build path pass it as a argument during the build process.

```
vite build --base=/my/public/path/
```

source: [vite docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#public-base-path)

Comment: For a relative root, you can then use: `vite build --base=./`